# Update for Serializers with many=True only create is supported in django api

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, insert-update

I am using many in my serializer for creating new fields . I need to implement update in order to add the new fields coming and leave the existing ones as it is. Mycode is given below.

models.py

```
class Device(models.Model):
   device_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   auth_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ThirdPartyApps(models.Model):
   auth_token = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   app_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

serializers.py

```
class AppSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Apps
        fields = ('app_name', 'auth_token_id')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if "auth_token_id" in self.context:
            id1 = self.context["auth_token_id"]
            instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
            user_id = id1
            if user_id is not None:
                instance.auth_token_id = user_id
                instance.save()
            return instance
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add_apps(request):
    data = request.data
    auth_token = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHTOKEN', '')
    auth_tok = Device.objects.get(auth_token=auth_token)
    a_id = auth_tok.id
    serializer = AppSerializer(ThirdPartyApps, data=data, context={"auth_token_id": a_id}, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        content = collections.OrderedDict(
                [('status', True), ('message', "Third party apps are saved")])
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

I tried to use the update support of django by giving the model name while passing it to serializer to call the update method. But it says that when many=True , update is not supported only create method is supported . It is suggesting to use a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update() in my serializers. I am unable to understand how to use it. I just want to update my fields .

Answer (score 2):

The argument for the serializer instantiation should be an instance and not a `Model`.

```
serializer = AppSerializer(ThirdPartyApps, data=data, context={"auth_token_id": a_id}, many=True)
```

You need to replace `ThirdPartyApps` by the instance list you want to update.

You'll also need to follow the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-update) about how to handle multiple update.

Comment: I tried it exactly the same way but when many=True it only supports create but not  update . I went through the documentation link already but i am unable to understand how to add an explicit id field to the instance serializer.

Comment: It is giving this error - Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default, only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with insertions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update()` so you can specify the behavior exactly.

Comment: You didn't mention that id thing in the initial question. You didn't provide an update function as explained in the documentation. Please closed that question and start a new one.